# Why won't my code run on my physical device (iOS)

Tags: javascript, xcode, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I'm building a practice app from scratch again with React Native to start off fresh. On my previous project, I ran code on my iPhone 5 (physical device) just fine with Xcode.

But now, since I started a brand new project, it gives me these errors when I run my code on Xcode (when I hit the play button):

> Signing for "myAppName" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>
> Code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

The thing is, I'm already in a development team that of which I selected under `Signing` in Xcode.

I remember when doing my old project, I had to verify my account or something like that on my iPhone by navigating to `Settings > General` and then after that I had verify my app so that it can successfully run on my iPhone.

I've searched this up on SO for quite some time and the answers that I'm seeing aren't rectifying my issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
what does it say for your signing team? Also check the preferences to see if you have the agent or the personal team selected. It needs to be the Agent. If that doesnt work, can you send a screenshot to supply more info?